# How can I use the SonarQube community edition (6.7) to verify the quality of the feature branches of my project?

Tags: git, sonarqube, branch

How can I use the SonarQube community edition (6.7) to verify the quality of the feature branches of my project?
I would like to have a main SonarQube project for the master branch and a seperate SonarQube project for each feature branch.

In SonarQube versions < 6.7 I was using the -Dsonar.branch parameter to indicate it is a branch. 
From the documentation of SonarQube I read that the branch parameter is deprecated since 6.7

So what I'm currently trying to do is next:
I use the next two parameters to push the master branch to SonarQube
-Dsonar.projectKey=project_master -Dsonar.projectName=project_master

I use the next three parameters to push my feature branches to SonarQube
-Dsonar.projectKey=project_feature1 -Dsonar.projectName=project_feature1 -Dsonar.branch=feature1
-Dsonar.projectKey=project_feature2 -Dsonar.projectName=project_feature2 -Dsonar.branch=feature2

Because the "sonar.branch" is deprecated the next line is visible in the log: "[WARNING] The use of "sonar.branch" is deprecated and replaced by "sonar.branch.name". See https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/branches.html."

But strangly the feature branches still are ending up correctly in SonarQube as a unique SonarQube project!

When I change the param "sonar.branch" to "sonar.branch.name" I get the error message: "To use the property "sonar.branch.name", the branch plugin is required but not installed."

When I omit the param "sonar.branch" I get the message: Module "" is already part of project "".

So I'm a bit lost here. Although "sonar.branch" is deprecated in 6.7 it still works somehow?

If not, what should I do to have a unique SonarQube project for each of my feature branches by using the SonarQube community edition?

Or is there another way to monitor the quality of the feature branches?

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated doesn't mean that it doesn't work anymore, only that it will be removed at some point in the future. So you can continue to use `sonar.branch`, but you've been warned that sometime in the future this feature will disappear.

Removal of `sonar.branch` will not happen before next LTS release, which will be *probably* in 2019

However, if you can, I highly recommend [branch feature](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin) available in developer edition, it's much more robust and rounded than the old approach.

Answer (score 1):

@dj van kessel - SonarQube Community is free to analyze any branches in public repositories.
If you have a private repo, you can analyze the master branch. 
If you need to analyze on feature/pr branches, it means you're using advanced features of SonarQube, and it's time to [recognize](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/) the hard work of the SonarQube team.

Comment: Agree... But try explaining that to a customer

Comment: You can still monitor quality on the master branch if needed.